# Babel Standalone React Import Statement resolves to wrong file

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am using babel standalone to create a react page without the use of node. When including the react components in the head of the html page a 'text/babel' it seems that components overwrite each other.

See the following minimalist example:

Component A:

```
const ComponentA = props => {

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Component A</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default ComponentA;
```

Component B:

```
const ComponentB = props => {

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Component B</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default ComponentB;
```

Components Index:

```
import ComponentA from './ComponentA/index.js';
import ComponentB from './ComponentB/index.js';

export { ComponentA, ComponentB };
```

Index HTML Head:

```
<script>
  Babel.registerPreset('custom-react-preset', {
    presets: [[Babel.availablePresets['es2017'], { modules: false }], [Babel.availablePresets['react']]],
    plugins: [[Babel.availablePlugins['transform-modules-umd']]]
  });
</script>

<!-- COMPONENTS -->
<script type="text/babel" src="./components/ComponentA/index.js" data-presets="custom-react-preset"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="./components/ComponentB/index.js" data-presets="custom-react-preset"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="./components/index.js" data-presets="custom-react-preset"></script>
```

Now, when importing either ComponentA or ComponentB from the components index file, the resulting component is ALWAYS ComponentB. Note the order of the component script tags in the head. If I swap the order, the import ALWAYS results in componentA.

How can this be? Do I need some additional babel configuration?